# Autofocus not working on open form dialog with button component in Material UI v5

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Anyone knows why autofocus in TextField are not working in open dialog form with button component?

```
      <TextField
        autoFocus
        margin="dense"
        id="name"
        label="Email Address"
        type="email"
        fullWidth
        variant="standard"
      />
```

See **[here](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-dialog/#form-dialogs)**, it's working!
[image: it's working!]

See **[here](https://codesandbox.io/s/3ccf8c?file=/demo.tsx)**, it's dont working!
[image: it's dont working!]

But if you use a component link it works!
See **[here](https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-dubinsky-9cxjyv)**!
[image]

Comment: Good catch!  It is interesting that it works on the MUI example page but not on CodeSandbox or Stackblitz.  I tried to pass the `autoFocus` property via both `InputProps` and `inputProps` and could not get a focus those ways either.  

Can anyone shine light on how a link is different than an `onClick` callback on a Button?  Perhaps a bug?

Comment: Another thing!  I changed the `Button` component to a `Typography` and `Box` with the same `onClick` handler and it worked fine.  I assume it would work with any MUI component other than Button.  A `Button` bug?

Comment: Exactly! Add this in Code Sandbox, See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)!

Comment: It seems to be a bug in the "restore focus" functionality -- focus goes very briefly to the text field and then returns to the button. If I add the `disableRestoreFocus` prop to the dialog, it works correctly. I can't yet explain why it works on the documentation site.

Comment: Here's the relevant existing issue: https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/33004. If you remove strict mode it works. It is probably a bug only surfaced in dev mode where strict mode executes some things twice to surface bugs like this.

Comment: It works in the docs because they are using the production react build.

Comment: @RyanCogswell, I added `disableRestoreFocus` and it worked correctly, please include your answer so I can mark it as correct, thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: @CleitonFreitas I did that as a debugging step, but that has a negative effect on accessibility and I don’t recommend doing that. Since ithe issue only affects dev mode, I recommend living with it — it will work fine in production.

Answer (score 9):

Take a look at this: https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/33004#issuecomment-1455260156.
Adding `disableRestoreFocus` to `<Dialog>` worked for me!